# Sles10 zypper can not add repository

Tags: linux, sles, zypper

I would like to add a new local repository of SLES 10 SP4 on my System.
 But zypper gives Problems. Here is what I tried so far,

#zypper ar /some/local/dir local {I have copied all the SLES10 RPMs inside this dir}
 Unknown command 'ar'.

zypper sa /usr/repo/sp4 local
 URL is invalid.
 Url scheme is a required component

Is there anything I am missing?
 Please suggest.

Thanx.

Admin

Answer (score 0):

It works with following command,

sa -t Plaindir file:///somedir

Thanx anyways.